# Difference between "drive.metadata.readonly" and "drive.readonly.metadata"

Tags: google-app-engine, google-drive-api, service-accounts

I want to ask what is the **difference** between `DriveScopes.DRIVE_METADATA_READONLY` and `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly.metadata`? In other words, what is the difference between
these two forms:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata.readonly //DriveScopes.DRIVE_METADATA_READONLY
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly.metadata
```

When I was using **service account** for working with **Drive API** it takes me a long time to figure out, why my app was throwing *unauthorized exception*:

```
Uncaught exception from servlet
com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.TokenResponseException: 403
{
    "error" : "access_denied",
    "error_description" : "Requested client not authorized."
}
```

The String constant `DriveScopes.DRIVE_METADATA_READONLY` was causing the exception. In which context should I use this constant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's clearly a mistake in the Java API client.

The [API documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/web/scopes) states that the correct scope is :

```
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly.metadata
```

Whereas when you look at [the latest javadoc](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/drive/v2/java/latest/) (at the time of this answer), you get :

```
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata.readonly
```

You should ignore the `DriveScopes` constant and create your own constant, while the Google Drive team fixes this.

Comment: The API documentation now redirects to https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/about-auth which documents https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata.readonly , though I've been using drive.readonly.metadata without an issue....