# Google Drive Service Account get change list .is it possible?

Tags: android, google-app-engine, google-drive-api

In Android APP of service Account authorization as well as a servlet in Appengine for Google service account for Drive API, Not able to get changes of List for page token it's returning an empty list.
But https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/changes/list
same pageToken returns list.

```
   Drive.Changes.List request1 = drive.changes().list("3420");
    ChangeList changes = request1.execute();
```

Note: same above code returns change list if using GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it's possible. Based from this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12697843/access-google-drive-api-returns-empty-file-list), maybe you have authenticated with a scope that doesn't give you permission to see those files.

> For example, the scope https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file only provides access to files created or opened by the app. You won't be able to access files created in the Google Drive interface or by other apps.
>
> If you want to access all the files, you'll have to use another scope. https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive, for example, gives you full, permissive scope to access all of a user's files.

You can find information about the available scopes [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/about-auth#what_scope_or_scopes_does_my_app_need).

Comment: While the answer is correct, it would be unusual for a Drive Service Account to contain any files that are not created by the app. By definition, a Service Account is dedicated to a single service/app.