# Google Drive API v3 drive.files.list only return 25 records for space "photos"

Tags: ios, rest, google-drive-api

GET https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files?spaces=photos&key={YOUR_API_KEY}

only return 25 records, even in API explorer, is it a bug?

Comment: This isn't really correct for SO. If you believe there is a problem with this webpage, you should really contact them on their forums.

Comment: Have you tried setting `pageSize` to a higher value (e.g: 100) ? How many results were you expecting ? Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12697843/access-google-drive-api-returns-empty-file-list (I know it says empty in the title, but most comments are still valid)

Comment: Add 'fields=*' and check if next page is set in the response

Comment: I've double checked and found it's not only 25 records, but still not all. It seems that it will not return the photos you just uploaded. @JoshKopen, thanks for you suggestion and I already tried but met some errors.